# Only first element shown in HTML

Tags: angular, html, typescript

I'm loading an array of "Client" in the NgOnInit function in my component. After this call, i want to initalize an array of the type "TimeSheet" which hold "Client" as element. I do this like this:

```
init(clients : Client[]) {
    let i = 0;
    this.timeSheets = new Array(clients.length);
    for(let client of clients) {
        console.log("client firstname" + client.firstName);
        this.timeSheets[i] = new TimeSheet();
        this.timeSheets[i].client = client;
        console.log("client last name in timesheet: " + 
        this.timeSheets[i].client.lastName);
        i++;
    }
}
```

The browser console prints show me the correct values of the client:

```
client firstname Hans
client last name in timesheet: Müller
client firstname John
client last name in timesheet: Smith
client firstname Marie
client last name in timesheet: Curie
```

However, in my HTML template, only the first element is shown. This is the section where i put in my front-end:

```
<tr *ngFor="let timeSheet of timeSheets ;trackBy: trackId">
    <td>{{timeSheet.client.lastName}}</td>
    <td>{{timesheet.client.firstName}}</td>
    <td><input type="text" (change)="calculate($index)"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
</tr>
```

Curiously, only the "lastName" of the "Client" in the very first "Timesheet" is displayed, and the rest seems to fail without indication why. Since my labels also have disappeard, I suppose there is some error in my html code. My browser console also indicated that "client" is undefined, which confused my since the first element is printed correctly.

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'client' of undefined
```

This is what is looks like: 
[image]

Also, the button label and the table headers are gone, so i presume, there is some error in the code. Please help me find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

{{timesheet.client.firstName}}
Should be
{{timeSheet.client.firstName}}
Note case

Comment: Jesus Christ, i'm an idiot. Sometimes just having somebody looking at the code helps :) Time for a break, i've been coding for 15 hours straight now :)